# Jaxb setting dynamic @XmlRootElement with Spring Web Services

Tags: spring, spring-ws, jaxb2

I have a Spring application that consumes a SOAP web services.  I have several classes that are quite simple and only differ in the `@XmlRootElement`.  I'm wondering if there's a way to create a more generic class that I can set the root element on dymanically.

Here's a few of the classes with only the root element being different.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="safetydate")
public class SafetyDateRequest extends Carrier411RequestImpl {
}

@XmlRootElement(name="checkallsafety")
public class SafetyGetAllRequest extends Carrier411RequestImpl {
}

@XmlRootElement(name="checksafetyupdates")
public class SafetyGetUpdatesRequest extends Carrier411RequestImpl {
}
```

In another class, I'm processing these classes in the following fashion:

```
private void sendRequest(Carrier411Request request, Carrier411ResponseHandler responseHandler) throws FaultCodeException {
    Carrier411Response response = (Carrier411Response) ws.marshalSendAndReceive(registry.get(request.getClass()), request);

    checkResponseForFault(response);

    responseHandler.handleResponse(request, response);
}
```

I know there's another version of `marshalSendAndReceive` that accepts a callback allowing you to modify the request before actually sending it, but I haven't figured out how to achieve what I'm trying to do.